# Dynamic Query  from GUI 

Tags: sql-server-2008, user-interface, dynamicquery

My Database stores the information of Students in a tables along with their course offerings in other tables. There are more associated tables.

Now I wanna create a form that looks like this : [image]

Depending on the search criterion, the Query shall be executed. 
**More than one criterions may be selected.** After hitting the search button, the various tupples shall be displayed.

Whats teasing me is how should i proceed with the Query part....???

Can anyone please help me out?
b.t.w. I use SQL 2008R2 along with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Someone please answer the Question.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want then you could use a stored procedure that looks something like this.

```
create procedure GetIT
  @Name varchar(10) = null,
  @AdminNo varchar(10) = null,
  @TickNo varchar(10) = null,
  @Course varchar(10) = null,
  @AcaYear varchar(10) = null
as

select T.YourColumnList
from YourTable as T
where  
  (T.Name    = @Name    or @Name    is null) and
  (T.AdminNo = @AdminNo or @AdminNo is null) and
  (T.TickNo  = @TickNo  or @TickNo  is null) and
  (T.Course  = @Course  or @Course  is null) and
  (T.AcaYear = @AcaYear or @AcaYear is null)
```

Depending on what radio buttons are selected you will pass a value or null as an argument.

[Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)